# Chain Names or Titles

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word, or phrase, that describes or denotes the phenomenon of multiple places or objects in an area sharing a specific, usually regional, name or title? The best example present is in the third *Pirates of the Caribbean* film, which features the town of Shipwreck in Shipwreck Cove of Shipwreck Island.

Comment: Like New York, New York. I'm not sure if New York, New York, New York is used.

Answer (score 1):

If it was a different place with the same name, you could use *namesake*.

> **Namesake** *noun*
>   A person or thing that has the same name as another: *Hugh Capet paved the way for his son and namesake to be crowned king of France*; *unlike its Scottish namesake, Leven is not by the sea*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/namesake)

In your example, though it might be better to consider saying something along the lines of "... the town of Shipwreck in the *eponymous* Cove and Island".

> **Eponymous** *adjective*
>   of, relating to, or being the person or thing for whom or which something is named
>   [- M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eponymous)